# posts from users whose account was destroyed

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/4618/why-do-we-need-hardware-programmers) received 3 totally irrelevant posts within a few minutes (in German!) from the same user. User account was appropriately destroyed, but the posts were just deleted. For most users that's not a problem as they can't see deleted posts, but users with +10,000 rep *can* see the abusive posts. I don't want to see them!

Can't posts from a destroyed user account be destroyed as well?

Comment: Give me 33k rep, I can stand that view ;)

Comment: Offer a 40k bounty and you won't see them anymore.

Comment: I would support this... If an account is destroyed, everything that account did should also be destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

You can see the deleted posts as a part of peer review.  Those posts were deleted because they were nonsense, others are deleted because they're not answers: some are converted to comments or edits.  Still others are deleted by the author because they don't think the post is valuable. These deletions need to be reviewed; they're based on subjective judgements.  Perhaps a mod made an error and deleted an answer erroneously, or a user made a good question but didn't want their lack of knowledge to be known: These posts ought to be undeleted.

You're right, destroying users is generally for egregious cases and could be hard-deleted.  However, destroying users is also based on a judgement call.  We've had several cases in which users promoted their projects and companies by mentioning it in all their answers.  After some comments, some of these users turned out to be great contributors!  However, we could have destroyed these accounts.

For cases in which something really needs to be deleted from everyone's view (perhaps someone posted confidential/NDA'ed information or login credentials), developers can hard-delete content.  In these cases, email them via the contact us (mailto:team+electronics@stackexchange.com) link in the footer or raise a mod flag and a community mod will contact them.

Deleted posts are a small ratio of the posts on the site.  If one bothers you, you can edit it to be a single space, a haiku, or a cat picture.  Requests to delete posts which simply bother you will be ignored.